# Bochs executed an unexpected instruction after switching from protected mode to real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system

I am writing an x86 program to boot the operating system. When I tried to switch from protected mode to real mode, I encountered a very confusing problem. Sample code looks like this:

```
#file bootload.S

#include "bootmain/entry.h" # import some macro
.global entry

# loaded in 0x7c00 (512 Byte)
.text
entry:
.code16
     xor %ax, %ax
     mov %ax, %ds
     mov %ax, %es
     mov %ax, %ss

     mov $entry, %ax
     mov %ax, %sp
     cld

     # Reset the display mode to 80*25 color text mode
     mov $0, %ah #Function number: Set display mode
     mov $3, %al #The target mode is 80*25 color text mode
     int $0x10

     # Print greeting string
     mov $hellomsg, %bp #ES:BP points to the string buffer
     mov $0x13, %ah #BIOS INT function: display string
     mov $1, %al #Update the cursor after displaying the string
     mov $0, %bh #Set page number to 0
     mov $0x1f, %bl #Display attributes
     xor %dx, %dx
     mov hellomsglen, %cx #Set the string length
     int $0x10

     lgdt gdtdesc
     movl %cr0, %eax
     orl $1, %eax
     movl %eax, %cr0

     ljmp $0x8, $protcseg

     .code32
protcseg:
     movw $0x10, %ax
     movw %ax, %ds
     movw %ax, %es
     movw %ax, %fs
     movw %ax, %gs
     movw %ax, %ss

     # Now turn off p-mode
     movl %cr0, %eax
     xorl $1, %eax
     movl %eax, %cr0

     ljmp $0, $realseg
realseg:
     xor %ax, %ax
     mov %ax, %ds
     mov %ax, %es
     mov %ax, %ss
     mov %ax, %fs
     mov %ax, %gs
    # Now try again with INT 0x10
     # Print greeting string
     mov $hellomsg, %bp #ES:BP points to the string buffer
     mov $0x13, %ah #BIOS INT function: display string
     mov $1, %al #Update the cursor after displaying the string
     mov $0, %bh #Set page number to 0
     mov $0x1f, %bl #Display attributes
     xor %dx, %dx
     mov hellomsglen, %cx #Set the string length
     int $0x10
```

Now I use Bochs to debug this program, and I found that the second time I used the interrupt, an unexpected instruction appeared in the interrupt routine and the program jumped to the wrong memory address. The debugging process of two interrupt calls is shown in the figure below:
first
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3MoR.png)
second
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl3Gd.png)

I tried modifying the code as suggested on OSDevWiki, but the same problem still occurred:

```
#include "bootmain/entry.h"
.global entry

.text
entry:
.code16
     xor %ax, %ax
     mov %ax, %ds
     mov %ax, %es
     mov %ax, %ss

     mov $entry, %ax
     mov %ax, %sp
     cld

     # Reset the display mode to 80*25 color text mode
     mov $0, %ah #Function number: Set display mode
     mov $3, %al #The target mode is 80*25 color text mode
     int $0x10

     # Print greeting string
     mov $hellomsg, %bp #ES:BP points to the string buffer
     mov $0x13, %ah #BIOS INT function: display string
     mov $1, %al #Update the cursor after displaying the string
     mov $0, %bh #Set page number to 0
     mov $0x1f, %bl #Display attributes
     xor %dx, %dx
     mov hellomsglen, %cx #Set the string length
     int $0x10

     lgdt gdtdesc
     movl %cr0, %eax
     orl $1, %eax
     movl %eax, %cr0

     ljmp $0x8, $protcseg

     .code32
protcseg:
     movw $0x20, %ax
     movw %ax, %ds
     movw %ax, %es
     movw %ax, %fs
     movw %ax, %gs
     movw %ax, %ss

     ljmp $0x18, $realseg
realseg:
# Now turn off p-mode
     movl %cr0, %eax
     xorl $1, %eax
     movl %eax, %cr0
     xor %ax, %ax
     mov %ax, %ds
     mov %ax, %es
     mov %ax, %ss
     mov %ax, %fs
     mov %ax, %gs

     # Print greeting string
     mov $hellomsg, %bp #ES:BP points to the string buffer
     mov $0x13, %ah #BIOS INT function: display string
     mov $1, %al #Update the cursor after displaying the string
     mov $0, %bh #Set page number to 0
     mov $0x1f, %bl #Display attributes
     xor %dx, %dx
     mov hellomsglen, %cx #Set the string length
     int $0x10

hellomsg:
.string "helloworld"
hellomsglen:
.word . - hellomsg
.p2align 2
gdt:
     SEG(0, 0, 0) #Empty segment descriptor (GDT must start with this)
     SEG(0x2|0x8 ,0, 0xffffffff) #Code segment, [0x0, 0xffffffff], readable and executable
     SEG(0x2,0, 0xffffffff) #Data segment, [0x0, 0xffffffff], readable and writable
     SEG(0x2|0x8,0, 0xffff) #Code segment, [0x0, 0xffffffff], readable and executable
     SEG(0x2,0, 0xffff) #Data segment, [0x0, 0xffffffff], readable and writable
gdtdesc:
     .word 0x27
     .long gdt
```

Comment: You forgot a `.code16` before `realseg`. Also according to the screenshot, the second invocation is still running in 32 bit mode.